# how to call Laravel 8.x Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to laravel, I just installed it and used migrations files to create the database successfuly. Next step is to use the models. I need to use eloquent just as an ORM, I do not need to include the whole MVC stuff because I need to call the models from an outside project.
So my model is

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

     protected $fillable = [
         'name',
         'users_username',
         'email',
         'password',
     ];
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'users_id';
}
?>
```

And I am calling it from a test.php file in the root

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Models\Users;

$users = Users::where('users_username', 'adriana')
    ->orderBy('users_username')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();

print_r(Users::all() );
?>
```

Simply calling "php test.php" from the command line, both statements give an error such as:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /var/www/html/orm/laravel-8.x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1493
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/orm/laravel-8.x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1459): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection()
#1 /var/www/html/orm/laravel-8.x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1266): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getConnection()
#2 /var/www/html/orm/laravel-8.x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1183): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#3 /var/www/html/orm/laravel-8.x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1219): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newModelQuery()
#4 /var/www/html/orm/laravel-8.x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1172): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#5 /var/www/html/orm/laravel-8.x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1885): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery()
#6 /var/www/html/orm/laravel-8.x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1897): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call()
#7 /var/www/html/orm/laravel-8.x/test.php(16): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic()
#8 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/orm/laravel-8.x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 1493
```

I also inserted some data in the database as I thought that was the problem yet it still doesn't work
I don't know what I should add to the model or to test.php
How can I fix it in order to simply call this model?
I have read and searched and I can't seem to find out how to fix it, how to use Models, all tutorials seem simple and clear yet nothing I tried worked.
Thanks for your help

Comment: where your `test.php` is located?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? if you're writing tests, use ```php artisan make:test TestUsers```, you said you want to ```call the models from an outside project```, then set a route for the resource, like ```Route::get('/users', function () {
    return Users::where('users_username', 'adriana')
    ->orderBy('users_username')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
});``` to access the data via http request to GET /users from your outside project.

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro what i'm understanding is that she installed the whole laravel framework but wants only the ORM part and is trying to use it from outside laravel in a simple php file.

Comment: Yes @JoeRR, I understood that part, that's why I'm asking what is OP trying to accomplish. Let OP answer.

Comment: Hi, test.php is in the root of the laravel project.

Comment: I am trying to use laravel just for the ORM part which is db migration and using models to access the database. The file could have been called anything php, I am not testing, just trying to use the model to extract data from database. Without going through views, routes an dall the MVC stuff. So I am calling the model from a simple php file and I don't know what to add to it to make it work since I don't have a lot of experience with laravel

Comment: You don't need to set the views or the controllers to use the models in Laravel, but truly, it seems like too much to use the whole Laravel framework when you just want the ORM, use Lumen at least, or try [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-illuminate-database-with-eloquent-in-your-php-app-without-laravel--cms-27247)